# Getting VIEW metadata from SQL Server using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, schema

I'm trying to get description of the views on my database, and I tried joining `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS` with `sys.extended_properties`.

Problem is that I can't find ID in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS`

Anyone know how to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'description'?

Comment: @dfundako Description in metadata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get the object's id like this:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type='v'
```

You might join the extended properties like this

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects AS o
INNER JOIN sys.extended_properties AS ep ON ep.major_id=o.object_id;
```

Comment: Or better yet: use the **focused** `sys.views` catalog view instead of having to remember what obscure `type` a view has in `sys.objects` ....

Comment: @marc_s Well, yes, fair point. But - to be honest - a "V" to mark a VIEW is not very obscure :-)

Comment: Well yes - for the view it's pretty obvious - and therefore, you'd *think* it would be `t` for table and `f` for function - right?!?!?

Comment: @marc_s btw; You brought up the *f for function* There is no *focused* view for this... :-)